# How to count all records and pull last activity date

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

i'm a newb so apologies and many thank you's in advance!
I have this query which ultimately i want to:

1. count # of customers terr has
2. count # of customers contacted in last 60 days
3. where customer contacted, then populate the last F.call_dt, F.Last_Call_Date, F.call_nbr

SAMPLE DATA:

```
Row...Terr......call_dt......Last_Call_Date.....call_nbr.....acct_#.....#_aligned.........contact.........compliance

1.......SR 1.......?................?.............?............6853.........1..............0.................0

2.......SR 1.......?................?.............?.............370.........1..............0.................0

3.......SR 1...6/23/2019....6/23/2019 .........75001..........784370........1..............1.................1  ** 

4.......SR 1.......?................?.............?...........784370........1..............0.................0
```

Here's what i would LIKE to see:

```
Row...Terr......call_dt......Last_Call_Date.....call_nbr.....acct_#.....#_aligned.........contact.........compliance

1.......SR 1.......?................?..............?.............6853........1..............0................0

2.......SR 1.......?................?..............?..............370........1..............0................0

3.......SR 1...6/23/2019.......6/23/2019 .........75001........784370........1..............1................1
```

Comment: Perhaps a bit more complex than needed, but... instead of `F.contact_stat as contacted,` don't you want `max(F.contact_stat) as contacted,` (and remove this column from the final `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You group by `F.cntry_enti_nbr`, thus `count (distinct F.cntry_enti_nbr)` will always be 1. Remove it from Select/Group By

Comment: Thanks Fred and dnoeth.  I have implemented both of your suggestions. However, still producing two records for acct #784370.

Comment: Of course, based on call_dt......Last_Call_Date.....call_nbr being NULL/NOT NULL. You might add another QUALIFY, but I doubt it will work as expected, you probably group to much and as Fred said, it seems to be overly complicated.

Comment: @dnoeth Not sure how to implement your suggestion.  Indeed what I would like to say is if there are no calls in the last 60 days, then # contacted is 0 and leave last call date, call date and call_nbr blank.

if there is a call in the last 60 days, then give me the latest call details.

Answer (score -1):

with help of a colleague i was able to achieve my desired results by adding this qualify rank() over() statement to ensure that I only get the latest last_call_dt information:

```
qualify rank() over (partition by terr, acct # order by call_dt) = 1
```

Hope this is helpful to someone!